# cant get this formula to work, although the top and bottom code works fine

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I did a search on this site, but can't find an answer to my problem. I am using VB 2010 Express. I'm trying to write formulas into a Excel spreadsheet.

```vb
oWorkSheet = oBook.Sheets(STRName)
'my variables are all declared strings

'this section works

FMLAValue1 = "=-L8"
FMLAValue2 = "=SUM($I$7;$F$8:$H$8)"
FMLAValue3 = "=SUM(M8:U8)"

oWorkSheet.Range("H8").Select()
oWorkSheet.Range("H8").Formula = FMLAValue1
oWorkSheet.Range("H8").AutoFill (oWorkSheet.Range("H8:H40"))

'up to here

'now this is the problem code below: if I paste the formula into a
'excel sheet cell, it works.

oWorkSheet.Range("I8").Select()
oWorkSheet.Range("I8").Formula = FMLAValue2

'**the line above gives an "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC "**

oWorkSheet.Range("I8").AutoFill (oWorkSheet.Range("I8:I40"))

'this part also works

oWorkSheet.Range("L8").Select()
oWorkSheet.Range("L8").Formula = FMLAValue3
oWorkSheet.Range("L8").AutoFill (oWorkSheet.Range("L8:L40"))

oWorkSheet.Range("J7").Select()
oWorkSheet.Range("J7").Formula = "=I7"
```

Comment: Try using `FormulaLocal` instead of `Formula`, or replace the semi-colon with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

The formula stored in your `FMLAValue2` variable doesn't look correct, you shouldn't have a `;` (semi-colon) to separate the numbers, you should use a `,` (comma).

Use this instead:

```
FMLAValue2 = "=SUM($I$7,$F$8:$H$8)"
```

and you should hopefully be ok, unless there are other issues somewhere that I haven't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

To test whether a formula is correct, use [FormulaDesk](http://www.formuladesk.com). It will immediately tell you if there is an error, and pinpoint exactly where it is in your formula. You can then paste the formula into your VBA code, knowing that it works.

The image below shows how it can pinpoint exactly where your error is within the formula. So in your case, paste the non-working error into a cell in Excel, then view the error report in FormulaDesk to find out the exact cause.

*[Disclosure: I am the author of FormulaDesk. I think it will definitely help the poster find any errors]*

[image]